# `git stash list` doesn't show the before-the-slash part of branch names

Tags: git

I have a post-checkout hook that uses `git stash list` to see if there's a stash in the current branch, and tells the user if there is one.

It's failing when the branch has a slash in it, like `feature/footest`, because the message created by 'git stash' doesn't include the `feature/` part:

```
$ git status
On branch feature/footest
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    modified:   config/locales/en.yml

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

$ git stash
Saved working directory and index state WIP on footest: 5a81e44c1f Couple more
```

So, the message that's automatically created by `git stash` is

`WIP on footest: 5a81e44c1f Couple more`

Then, later, my code checks that message (when output from `git stash list`) to see if the branch matches the current branch, and decides that it doesn't, because "feature/footest" doesn't equal "footest".

I don't want to assume that "feature/footest" and "footest" are the same thing.  Ideally I'd like `git stash` to change its automatically generated name for the stash to include the full branch name.  Is this possible?

I'm using git version 2.34.1 on macos.

EDIT 1

- answer to @j6t's comment:

```
$ git show-ref | grep footest
5a81e44c1ff2930f02047d17f75364d8a8d0e20f refs/heads/feature/footest
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce with Git 2.36.0 on Windows. What does `git show-ref` report about your branch?

Comment: with some scripting and `git stash push -m` option you could custom stash message if it does not fit your needs.

Comment: @j6t i've added to my question in an edit, thanks

Comment: @Maxime the problem with custom messages (the -m option) is that it doesn't change the branch name - it only changes the part after the colon.

Comment: @MaxWilliams sure but you can add full branch name in message as workaround. It definitely comes from the version (`2.36.1` on linux working fine as well). Another solution, if you cannot upgrade `git` on your system and have `docker`, would be to use a docker image with a shared volume for your code.

Comment: I upgraded to 2.36.1 and that fixed it - thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this was simply to upgrade git.  I'm now on v2.36.1 and the automatically generated stash message now shows the full branch name.

BTW in case anyone's interested this is my post checkout hook that tells me if I have stashed changes in the branch.  It's really useful for an absent-minded programmer like myself.

```
$ cat .git/hooks/post-checkout
#!/bin/sh
branch=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
stashes=`git stash list | grep "WIP on $branch"`
if [ "$stashes" ]
then
  echo "You have the following stashes for this branch:"
  echo $stashes
fi
```

Comment: That's a nice post-checkout hook idea, thanks for sharing!

Comment: Not going to be a problem but you might want to test `[ -n "$stashes" ]`, i.e., nonzero length, or to be really paranoid, `[ x != x'$stashes" ]` in case `$stashes` expands to `-lt` or something equally silly. It literally can't here because of the grep, so this is entirely safe as is, but it's a good habit to get into. The `echo` probably should be `printf "%s\n" "$stashes"` for the same sort of reason, with the same sort of can't-really-happen going on for this case.

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug added during the conversion of `git stash` from shell script to C code.  The bug was present in Git versions 2.22 through 2.35 (fixed in 2.36.0; see [<sup><sub>commit `ceaf037f617eb774bb8a451c1779dd9b8b12152a`</sub></sup>](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ceaf037f617eb774bb8a451c1779dd9b8b12152a)).  Note that the only effect of the bug is to represent "multilevel" branch names incorrectly in the stash's default title / subject line.  That is, stashing while on branch `fie` says `WIP on fie` but `stashing on foo/bar/baz` generated `WIP on baz` instead of `WIP on foo/bar/baz`.